# Why does MongoDb crash with "Got signal: 7 (Bus error)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

My MongoDb crashes with the following message:

```
Invalid access at address: 0x7f155d0f10b0
[conn21] SEVERE: Got signal: 7 (Bus error).
```

MongoDb ran without problems for months. I can restart mongodb after each crash but after a few hours it fails again.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the version of MongoDB?

Comment: I use version 2.6.12

Comment: Please refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947465/mongodb-crashed-with-invalid-access-at-address-segmentation-fault-signal-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a restart of my production environment it turned out that the harddisk was dead :(